# How to add comms after every number from array using for loop in Java

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop

I am trying to bring this output: `65, 3, 10` (no comma at the end)

but with my code, I am getting this: `65, 3, , 10`

Can anyone help me to write the correct code, please?
Here is my code:

```
static void printArray(int[] validInput, int arrayFill){    //validInput[] = {65, 3, 10};  arrayFill = 3;(size of array)
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayFill; i++)
    {
        for(int j = 0; j < i; j++)
        {
            System.out.print(", ");
        }
        System.out.print(validInput[i]);
    }
}
```

Comment: instead of for-loop, use `if` condition.

Comment: Since you only have to add `,` at most once in each iteration, use `if` condition for that. Inner for-loop is not required. Check @CesareIsHere answer for reference.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i dont' know why you used a double for but with this solution (a for with an if condition that stops to print ',' when index is equal to the last cycle) you have the desired output

```
static void printArray(int[] validInput, int arrayFill){    //validInput[] = {65, 3, 10};  arrayFill = 3;(size of array)
    for(int i = 0; i < arrayFill; i++)
    {
        System.out.print(validInput[i]);
        
        if(i!=arrayFill-1) {
             System.out.print(", ");
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

```
65, 3, 10
```

Comment: Thanks mate!! I don't know how did I forget about this way.